# Attempt to index nil with 'Connect' With Changed event

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

I am having the error:

> ```
> attempt to index nil with 'Connect'  -  Client - LocalScript:3
> ```

I am trying to make it so that when a string value gets updated, it will update the GUI text with it

```
local status = game.Workspace.Status.Value

status.Changed:Connect(function()
    script.Parent = status
end)
```

The tutorial that I'm following: [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXttDSvsdes&list=PLQzvopOmicp7MQ4wV_VgRqC4pHrl_bALZ&index=1&ab_channel=ZingoDev)

It is a local script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`game.Workspace.Status` is the StringValue. When you save the `.Value` into a variable, you aren't holding onto a reference to the StringValue itself, you are copying its value into the variable.

So you fix your problem, you just need your variable to point at the StringValue, not the string stored inside it.

```
local status = game.Workspace.Status

status.Changed:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Text = status.Value
end)
```

Comment: Thanks! I also forgot to make it say `script.Parent.text = status.value`